# What, in general, are the conditions for a chain reaction to die out, suddenly stop, stay constant, or accelerate?

Tags: nuclear-physics

In physics, as well as in other areas of science, there are many examples of a chain reaction.
The first thing that springs to mind almost Naturally, is the nuclear chain reaction: a neutron reacts with the core of a radioactive atom, after which a number of new neutrons are released. These neutrons...etc.
There is the nuclear fusion chain reaction (going on in the Sun at a steady-state, luckily for us), which is, apart from the details, similar to the nuclear chain reaction. It takes place at much, much higher energy though.
One has domino chains (for which, if the chain has infinite length, and the distances between all the stones are equal, it is clear that the chain continues forever, i.e. the chain reaction is constant, or the reaction suddenly stops if one stone is missing and one falling stone can't reach the next one).
There are many nice contraptions that use gravity to make things do the weirdest (and funniest) things (which is essentially the same as a domino reaction, which is mostly contained in these contraptions).

In a general chain reaction (I don't know if there **is** a general chain reaction, or that you have to look at each case separately; the nuclear fission chain reaction though is basically the same as the fusion chain reaction), what are the conditions for the reaction to die out like a burning candle approaching the point of "death", suddenly stop, stay constant, or accelerate? I've already mentioned some.

It may seem if these are four questions in one, but the single main subject is a chain reaction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take the classic case of a fission chain reaction. We'll simplify things a bit by assuming that all of the fission triggers (neutrons) released in a fission event have the right energy to cause more fissions, and that every nucleus that gets hit by a neutron does fission. Assume further a spherical mass of fissionable matter.

The criticality condition for self-sustaining fission then depends on two things: 1) the number of neutrons released by each fission event and the loss rate of neutrons out of the spherical volume. If the neutron generation rate is less than the loss rate, the mass is *subcritical* and the fissions die out. If the generation rate is bigger than the loss rate, the mass is *supercritical* and you get an explosion. If the rates are precisely equal (which is hard to achieve in practice without some means of fine-tuning and controlling the neutron flux inside the volume) you get a self-sustaining chain reaction.

The loss rate depends on the mean free path length of a loose neutron within the volume of the fissionable matter. Here you can see that if a supercritical mass is shaped into a rectangular slab instead of a sphere and the thickness of the slab is significantly less than the mean free path length, most of the neutrons will escape out the sides of the slab without triggering any fissions and the slab will be subcritical.

Richard Serber's excellent book *The Los Alamos Primer* goes through the physics of the whole process without these simplifications and explains how the physicists at Los Alamos figured out all the things required to design and build a bomb that would reliably explode.